# Isolate a specific column of values in an array of objects

Tags: php

I have an array of objects as follows:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [lid] => 2492
        [post_title] => Winter League 2012/2013
        [eid] => 2121
        [etitle] => a 2013
        [rid] => 2358
        [rtitle] => sdcc2013_2M_W
        [rtype] => W
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [lid] => 2492
        [post_title] => Winter League 2012/2013
        [eid] => 2121
        [etitle] => a 2013
        [rid] => 2359
        [rtitle] => sdcc2013_4M_M
        [rtype] => M
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [lid] => 2492
        [post_title] => Winter League 2012/2013
        [eid] => 2123
        [etitle] => e 2013
        [rid] => 2360
        [rtitle] => eircom_Women_2.5Mile
        [rtype] => W
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [lid] => 2492
        [post_title] => Winter League 2012/2013
        [eid] => 2123
        [etitle] => e 2013
        [rid] => 2362
        [rtitle] => eircom2013_men_5mile
        [rtype] => M
    )
```

and i want to 'get' the subset of 'rid' values

```
 (2358,2359,1360,2362)
```

which of array manipulation functions should i use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest `array_map()`.

```
$original_array; // your original array
$rid_array = array_map(function($val) {
    return $val->rid;
}, $original_array);
```

Or for PHP < 5.3

```
$original_array; // your original array
$rid_array = array_map('map_function', $original_array);

function map_function($val) {
    return $val->rid;
}
```

Comment: I believe he's looking to set them. Not get them.

Comment: I kind of took it as a typo in imprecise language issue, as the values shown are the same as those currently in the array of objects. So read it to mean, he wanted to set an array with the values rid values from the array of objects.

Comment: Is the callback function supported in PHP version 5.2.17?

Comment: @emeraldjava You need to be on PHP 5.3 or greater to utilize closures (anonymous functions) as shown.  See updated answer for compatibility with older versions of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with a callback function that sets the rid field of the object.

```
function set_rid($obj, $val)
{
    return $obj->rid = $val;
}

$my_rids = array(
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4'
);
array_map('set_rid', $my_array, $my_rids);
```

Comment: thanks - how to 'set' the values was going to be the next question